# Issue to import Adobe photoshop file in Expression Blend 4

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend-4

I tried to import Adobe photoshop file in Expression Blend 4.But Layer effects(Gradient Overlay,Stroke,etc) are ignored.
What should i do to import the Adobe photoshop file without ignoring layer effects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find what you're looking for [here](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/resources/BlendTraining/Day.aspx?day=5). With extra attention to Tutorial #1 & Tutorial #5, as not all your effects will carry over, which is where PixelShaders will come in handy. As for using Photoshop, well if you're just importing a Raster image it's not the same as importing vectors. These tutorials should help clarify.

You likely received the down vote because this is a rather common question that has been asked before on SO, and elswhere on the web so it shows a lack of personal effort before asking it. Hope this helps! :)